# InvalidPipeArgument: '18.06.2009' for pipe 'DatePipe'?

Tags: angular, datetime, datetime-format, angular2-pipe

I have this in .ts file :

```
 this.newDate = '18.06.2009';
```

In my html i have this:

```
  <h5 class="datetime">{{ newDate | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}}</h5>
```

Any suggestion what is wrong with this? How can i fix that so that i get:

```
1 June 2009
```

Comment: your data is not correct it needs to be like `newDate = new Date();`

Comment: You should probably read the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)  before instantly jumping to SO for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have set the date incorrectly , like a string it should be a `date` instance and also the pipe argument should be `'dd MMM yyyy'` instead of `'dd MMMM yyyy'`

```
newDate = new Date();

{{ newDate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}} // MMM instead of MMMM
```

Answer (score 0):

The [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) expects a timestamp(number) or a `Date` instance and you're sending a string as input. You can create the date object with something like:

```
this.newDate = new Date('06.01.2009')
```

and then it will work correctly. Have a look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info on how to work with dates.

Comment: @user1034912 why not ? have you tried and had any issues ?